# For loop over placeholder content Django CMS

Tags: django, placeholder, django-cms

I am trying to loop over a placeholder which returns for example: "word word word".

In my template I got this code:

```
 {% placeholder "categorie" as icon %}
 {% for i in icon.split %}
    <i class="{{ i }}"></i>
 {% endfor %}
```

However the **as** keyword is not working and the output is just the placeholder "word word word".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders in Django-CMS are intended to render content plugins. You can alter the contents of a placeholder programmtically (see "[Plugin Context Processors](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#plugin-context-processors)" for more), but you can't assign the content plugins contained within a placeholder using `as` to another variable.

They literally render their content plugins in the order that they appear in, top-down in Django admin for your model field.

Comment: So when I add 2 plain text plugings I can't loop over them. For example I have a placeholder "categories" and I add two plain text plugins: "word1" and "word2". Then I whish to loop over those 2 and give both of them a <i> tag?

Comment: Not in the way you're currently doing it. You could do post-processing on the placeholder contents, but as far as I know (someone please correct me if I'm wrong) you can't loop over the individual content plugins within a placeholder.